# Прикрутить новогоднюю шапочку к букве

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Хотел бы попросить о помощи в вопросе, написанном выше. Есть текст в контейнере, и есть изображение новогодней шапки. Каким образом можно наложить это изображение на букву? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы передо мной стояло такое задание, я подключил бы шрифт, на манеру **Kringle font**, а в коде применил бы его для этой буквы.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте в css свойство [`position: absolute;`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)  для шапки внутри контейнера, позиционирование шапки можно подогнать с помощью `left` и `top`.

Comment: Окей,попробую.Спасибо.

Comment: в представленном по ссылке примере, как раз ваш случай, контейнер и внутри него картинка с абсолютным позиционированием, так что можно оттуда частично стили взять

Comment: Тут проблема в том,что при масштабировании меняется положение шапки.

Comment: @Влад Иванов, можно обернуть первую букву в div с float:left и posotion:relative; ширину шапки задать как 100% и расположить точно над буквой ее с помощью top и left в % или em, а не px. Оборачивание буквы делается с помощью js.

Еще вариант использовать просто em в отсупах дя шапки, тогда отсупы будут привязаны к ширине символов и при масштабировании все будет правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -2.5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url("https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/6295b1f1b88d318118bf185c.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<h1>Новогоднее настроение</h1>
```